# Non-monotonically decreasing flow whose limit is $\vec{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to come up with $x'=Ax$, which is a system of linear differential equations, whose flow satisfies $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \lvert e^{tA}x\lvert = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, but $\lvert e^{tA} x\lvert$ is not monotonically decreasing.

I thought that in order to come up with an example of such a system, one would have to find a matrix $A$ with complex eigenvalues with negative real parts. But now I'm not so sure that this kind of an example would be correct since $e^{\Re e\{\lambda\}t}$ decreases much faster than the $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms would oscillate upwards. Yet, if we look at an example of the graph of such an oscillation, it usually does not decrease monotonically.

So where's the "catch"? I guess I'm conceptually wrong somewhere in my understanding of how $e^{\Re e\{\lambda\}t}$ dominates the trigonometric terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to consider nonreal eigenvalues. It is in fact sufficient to consider nontrivial Jordan canonical forms, such as 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &1\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The equation $x'=Ax$ has the properties that you want (draw the phase portrait or compute explicitly the solutions).

On the other hand, it is always possible to introduce a norm such that the map $t\mapsto \|e^{tA}x\|$ is strictly decreasing for all $x\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand your part about the norm though. Can you please explain?

Do you think that my matrix example (with complex eigenvalues) should work, too?

Comment: The part about the norm is quite technical, really impossible to detail without writing a lot (the idea goes back to Dalecki and Krein, although it didn't pass to many basic books). Sorry, but I can't afford the time for that. Yes, you can also have nonreal eigenvalues, provided that the Jordan canonical form is nontrivial (this is the important point). But for that you need a space of dimension at least $4$.